# run my sql dump in terminal

Tags: terminal, backup, mysql, dump

so I have can create a dump

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -u admin -p testsite  > yourdump.sql

but how do I run this on another mac in terminal?

Comment: You don't "run" a dump. You feed it back to mysql with `mysql -u admin -p testsite < yourdump.sql`.

Answer (score 3):

I should be as simple as running this:

```
mysql -u<user> -p dbName < db_backup.dump
```

Comment: achtung  mysql -u<user> -p dbName > db_backup.sql